# how to do real time notification in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, notifications

I have one requirement form in my application. So whenever user insert details in requirement form, after submit the mail will go to the particular vendor with link. When vendor clicks on that link, the link will redirect to the login page. After login then vendor gets redirected to vendor dashboard.

So what i want to do is, when ever user insert something in the requirement, the notification will go to the particular vendor dashboard after login like "you have one new requirement" like that

I have no idea on how to do this

Comment: http://socketo.me/, https://github.com/kishor10d/CodeIgniter-Ratchet-Websocket- but this is overall not a 1day task if you've no idea what sockets are ;)

Comment: an alternative would be repeatedly ajax calls to a controller who checks if there are new notifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After insert give call to `sendNotification` method which will take the inputs and send the notification with specified message and url to be landed.

I have implemented it using **onesignal** https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs.

Its very easy to use and implement.

1) Create an onesignal account. https://onesignal.com/
2) Create an google project and get the project id. https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-setup

Comment: it gives 404 not found ?

Comment: What have you done till now?

Comment: @NishantNair, the links you gave are subtly broken.  Not necessarily a bad test to see how much people can help themselves but may not be what you intended

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using concept of `transaction` on codeigniter.If records are successfully inserted into database then send `mail` with`link` as message which redirects to your `login` page.

Like this..

```
this->db->trans_begin();//start your transaction

//write queries to insert records into database
$this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
$this->db->query('ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->query('AND YET ANOTHER QUERY...');

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
{
        $this->db->trans_rollback();//rollback if insertion fails
}
else
{
        $this->db->trans_commit();//if insertion successful commit transaction 

         //write code to send mail
}
```

For more see [Codeigniter Transaction](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/transactions.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: for notification we need to create one table right?

Comment: ya insert your data into table and if success send mail with login page  link as message.

Comment: ya i already send mail with login page link..after login i need to show one notification in that dahsboard..like you got one new requirement like that

Comment: make a table notification with inserting messages and if login is success then retrieved this messages in descending order(based on id).